# How to redirect Symfony2 static assets to a controller request?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, symfony

How can I redirect a static asset in Symfony2 (e.g: JS, CSS or PDF file) to an actual controller action?

I'm trying to redirect this request (this used to represent a static asset which doesn't exist anymore):

```
http://localsite.dev/bundles/mybundle/misc/attachment.pdf
```

to this one (local dev site, this request is handled by a controller):

```
http://localsite.dev/app_dev.php/downloads
```

or this (live site):

```
http://livesite.com/downloads
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just set up a route for it in your routing.yml like any other route,

eg:

```
my_pdf_route:
    pattern: "/bundles/mybundle/misc/attachment.pdf"
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:PdfController:index }
```

Comment: Thanks! I've already tried this solution, but for whatever reason my cache was playing tricks on me. It worked after manually performing a cache clear.